# Dynamic masking from a Java program

Tags: java, api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, masking

I am new to Snowflake.
I am trying to understand if it is possible to set (and unset) dynamic masking on a specific column for certain roles from a **java program** and not using Snowflake web UI.
Is there an API to do this task?
Thanks
Yoram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set/unset a masking policy by executing an ALTER TABLE-statement.

Example from docs: `alter table empl_info modify column empl_id unset masking policy;`

More infos: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table-column.html

Regarding sending this statement from Java applications, you have to use the JDBC driver and its corresponding API: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-api.html